# How prevent user dragging scrollbar from moving the page?

Tags: javascript, html, events, scroll, dom-events

I don't want to remove the scrollbar. I want it there to indicate there's more to scroll, but even if they drag the scrollbar i want to prevent the page form moving (until a specific event occurs). How would I do this?

This does not work:

```
/* This does NOT stop the page form moving when the drag the scrollbar */
document.addEventListener( "scroll", function(event) {
     console.log( "scrolled");
     event.preventDefault(); 
     event.stopPropagation();
     return false;
  },
  false
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4atyw01h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just discovered one possible answer (it works): in addition to preventing default, propagation, you also need to set the element's `scrollTop` to be 0 (or wherever you want to lock it):

```
document.addEventListener( "scroll", function(event) {
     console.log( "scrolled");
     event.preventDefault(); 
     event.stopPropagation();

     //This stops it
     document.body.scrollTop = 0;

     return false;
  },
  false
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4atyw01h/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call the `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` methods. The `document.body.scrollTop = 0` assignment is enough. Call the `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` to prevent scrolling whole the document.
I tested in Chrome.